# I can call a function imported with dlsym() with a wrong signature, why?

Tags: c++, casting, shared-libraries, void-pointers, dlsym

host.cpp has:

```
int main (void)
{
    void * th = dlopen("./p1.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    void * fu = dlsym(th, "fu");

    ((void(*)(int, const char*)) fu)(2, "rofl");

    return 0;
}
```

And p1.cpp has:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" bool fu (float * lol)
{
    std::cout << "fuuuuuuuu!!!\n";
    return true;
}
```

(I intentionally left errors checks out)

When executing host, “fuuuuuuuu!!!” is printed correctly, even though I typecasted the void pointer to the symbol with a completely different function signature.

Why did this happen and is this behavior consistent between different compilers?

Comment: That cast is easily one of the ugliest corners of Posix... Maybe one day they'll fix that.

Comment: @KerrekSB, how can it be fixed without breaking everything?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: the best I can think of at the moment is a series of casts-to-char-pointers and `std::copy`, but it's far from pretty...

Comment: @KerrekSB, I'm not sure I even understand it. I don't see how you can make `dlsym()` return anything but `void*` without breaking things and I don't see how you can disallow the cast without breaking everything that relies on `dlsym()`. Is that what you were talking about?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: `dlsym` is broken even worse: It returns an *object* pointer, but wants you to interpret the result as a *function* pointer. That's not legal by any stretch of the imagination. What I'm saying is that you can't even write correct C++ that involves `dlsym` unless you jump through some serious hoops.

Comment: @KerrekSB sorry if I am not getting it correctly, you mean that typecasting a void pointer to a function is not correct C++?

Comment: @user1598585: No, that's indeed not allowed. :-( (You should be getting a warning if you enable enough diagnostics.)

Comment: @KerrekSB is compiling -Wall enough? because it is not complaining.

Comment: @user1598585: Add `-pedantic`. I get, `ISO C++ forbids casting between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object`. Alternatively, try storing the pointer: `void (*fp)(int, const char *) = fu;`

Comment: @KerrekSB seems it won’t work either, it says `error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void (*)(int, const char*)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there's no information about function signature in void pointer. Or any information besides the address. You might get in trouble if you started to use parameters, tho.

Comment: What did happen to the arguments I passed and the return value given by the function?

Comment: @user1598585: It's undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: What happened to them is not supposed to be consistent. They might, for instance, be pushed into stack and popped back. And the return value was passed as it normally is passed and discarded.

Comment: @EdS., as far as I understand the OP tries to understand what's *actually* happened. He doesn't seem to have expected it to work at all, so UB is no surprise for him :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Right, but it makes little sense to reason about what happened in the case of UB.  Sure, you may have a good idea what is going on, and you can always look at the disassembly to get the full picture, but in the end it is UB and the reason may change from compiler to compiler (or even if you modify the program, it's UB!)

Comment: Picked for being the only one assuming nothing more than just wanting to know the reason.

Comment: @EdS. *understanding* and having a good idea what's going on makes a lot of sense and is valuable itself.

Answer (score 5):

This happened because UB, and this behaviour isn't consistent with anything, at all, ever, for any reason.

Answer (score 2):

This actually isn't a very good example of creating a case that will fail since:

1. You never use the arguments from the function `fu`.
2. Your function `fu` has less arguments (or the activation frame itself is smaller memory-footprint-wise) than the function pointer-type you're casting to, so you're never going to end-up with a situation where `fu` attempts to access memory outside its activation record setup by the caller.

In the end, what you're doing is still undefined behavior, but you don't do anything to create a violation that could cause issues, so therefore it ends up as a silent error.

> is this behavior consistent between different compilers?

No. If your platform/compiler used a calling convention that required the callee to clean-up the stack, then oops, you're most likely hosed if there's a mis-match in the size of the activation record between what the callee and caller expect... upon return of the callee, the stack pointer would be moved to the wrong spot, possibly corrupting the stack, and completely messing up any stack-pointer relative addressing.

Answer (score 1):

It's just happened, that

- `C` uses `cdecl` call conversion (so caller clears the stack)
- your function does not use given arguments arguments

so your call *seems* to work correctly.

But actually behavior is undefined. Changing signature or using arguments will cause your program crash:

## ADD:

For example, consider `stdcall` calling conversion, where *callee* mast clear the stack. In this case, even if you declare correct calling conversion for both caller and callee, your program will still crash, because your stack will be corrupted, due to callee will clear it according to it signature, but caller fill according another signature:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

extern "C" __attribute__((stdcall)) __attribute__((noinline)) bool fu (float * lol) 
{
    std::cout << "fuuuuuuuu!!!\n";
    return true;
}

void x()
{
    (( __attribute__((stdcall)) void(*)(int, const char*)) fu)(2, "rofl");
}

int main (void)
{
    void * th = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&fu);

    std::string s = "hello";

    x();

    std::cout << s;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Changed both signatures in many ways and it did not crash, but maybe I just did not happen to find the case. And yes, I am totally aware that by messing with the arguments everything will be unexpected.

Comment: try changing calling conversion (I considered it as a part of signature).

Comment: Can you show me a little example plz, I am a little lost with the terminology.